# How to copy sub-folder from folder into another folder?

Tags: c#, console-application

I am working on C#.net console application in app i have two folders `1)D:\Working Projects\Alticore\AssetXML\LIS,  2)D:\Working Projects\Alticore\AssetXMLProcessed`.

Now i want to copy only sub-folder(i.e LIS) from `D:\Working Projects\Alticore\AssetXML\LIS to D:\Working Projects\Alticore\AssetXMLProcessed.`

That is xaclty like this `"D:\Working Projects\Alticore\AssetXMLProcessed/LIS"`.

Any solution to this problem I'll be appreciate.

Comment: And you want to do this in C#? The question is unclear

Comment: Yes iam working on c#.net

Comment: Move or copy. Pick one.

Comment: I would pinvoke SHFileOperation if you need to support XP. If you don't then there is IFileOperation.

Comment: Try to go with this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974019/folder-copy-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows XP, it would be thus:

```
move "c:\documents and settings\%USERNAME%\desktop\TZClock" "C:\documents and settings\%USERNAME%\Start Menu\Programs\TZClock"
```

On Windows 7, it is the following (though I'm not in a position to test this right now):

```
move "c:\users\%USERNAME%\desktop\TZClock" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\TZClock"
```

you can execute this process or another thing create new file copy all data.

Comment: No I want to copy only subfolder into another folder.

Comment: HI all...I want to create a folder with same name in source directory and copy related files into that folder.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
public static void Copy(String srcPath, String destPath)
{
    DirectoryInfo srcDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(srcPath);
    if (!srcDirectory.Exists) return;

    // Creates LIS directory
    destPath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(destPath, srcDirectory.Name));
    Directory.CreateDirectory(destPath);

    // Creates all sub directories from srcPath to your destPath
    foreach (String dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(srcPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(srcPath, destPath));

    // Copies all files from all sub directories from srcPath to your destPath
    foreach (String copyPath in Directory.GetFiles(srcPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        File.Copy(copyPath, copyPath.Replace(srcPath, destPath), true);
}
```

Usage:

```
Copy(@"D:\Working Projects\Alticore\AssetXML\LIS", @"D:\Working Projects\Alticore\AssetXMLProcessed")
```

If you don't want to copy sub folders or its files remove not needed foreach.
By the way it will override copied files.

Comment: Aldis...I want to copy only structure of folders and copy them into destination.

Comment: So removing last foreach should do the job or Im missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There is one more option what you can do is
there is
File.Copy(src, dest) method in the System.IO namespace you can also go with that.

Comment: That copies files and not directories

Comment: ok then you have to use mkdir kind of function & then copy that.

Comment: I know how to do it. I'm pointing out that your answer is wrong.