# how to share image copying from one folder to another folder Process in c#

Tags: c#

When we are copying images in one folder to another folder, images are going to copy one by one, then it takes more time when thousands's of images are copying, Is there any Possibility to copy Multiple images at a time? "This is My code"

```
              int avilableCharts = 0;
              int unavialableCharts = 0;
              string chartid;
              int count = 0;
                StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(txtFileName.Text);
                StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter("C:\\LogFiles\\SucessfullyMovedImages.txt");
                StreamWriter tw1 = new StreamWriter("C:\\LogFiles\\UnavailableImages.txt");
                DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(txtSourceFolder.Text);
                FileInfo[] file = dirinfo.GetFiles("*.pdf");
                while (!rd.EndOfStream)
                {
                    chartid = rd.ReadLine() + ".pdf";
                    count = count + 1;
                    worker.ReportProgress(count);
                    string FName = string.Empty;                      
                    if (File.Exists(txtSourceFolder.Text + chartid))

                    {
                        File.Copy(txtSourceFolder.Text + chartid , txtDestinationFolder.Text +          chartid );
                        avilableCharts = avilableCharts + 1;
                        tw.WriteLine(chartid);                            
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        unavialableCharts = unavialableCharts + 1;
                        tw1.WriteLine(chartid);
                    }

                }
                tw.Close();
                tw1.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Copied Images are :" + avilableCharts);
                MessageBox.Show("Total Unavilable Images are : " + unavialableCharts);
```

Comment: how are you copying the images?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Folder copy in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974019/folder-copy-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Please existing code... or things you have already researched and / or tried. In general, yes it is possible to copy multiple images at a time.. but there are several ways of doing it.. Please try to narrow down your question.

Comment: i am giving needed images numbers in one text file, based on that it will search in images folder, then i am copying to another folder(By using while loop and File.copy)

Answer (score 0):

use below code :

```
public class SimpleFileMove
 {
  static void Main()
   {
    string sourceFile = @"C:\Users\Public\public\test.txt";
    string destinationFile = @"C:\Users\Public\private\test.txt";

    // To move a file or folder to a new location:
    System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);

    // To move an entire directory. To programmatically modify or combine
    // path strings, use the System.IO.Path class.
    System.IO.Directory.Move(@"C:\Users\Public\public\test\", @"C:\Users\Public\private");
}
```

}

Comment: Move is not the same as Copy.

Comment: @shellshock : any error ??? and check permission , Is it administrator (your account)

Comment: look this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974019/folder-copy-in-c-sharp