# how to move folder which is located under program file with c# code

Tags: c#

I want to move folder which is located under program file folder with c# code.

Source path: '`C:\Program Files\MyApp\Testing`'
Target path: '`C:\`'
I wish to have: '`C:\Testing`'

Thanks.

Comment: I dont think there is any one liner .NET function to copy a directory,this is because of security.You need to write your own function to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Folder copy in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974019/folder-copy-in-c-sharp)

Comment: [Directory.Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move(v=vs.110).aspx) . but it is not going to be an easy task, your application will need high privileges.

Comment: @kyle you can use Directory.Move that is a oneliner