# Sub folders are not copyied

Tags: c#

I am using the function on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974019/folder-copy-in-c-sharp) to copy folders content into another folder, but it's not copying the sub folders and their content.

```
private static void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

    // If the source directory does not exist, throw an exception.
    if (!dir.Exists)
    {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
            "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
            + sourceDirName);
    }

    // If the destination directory does not exist, create it.
    if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
    {
        Debug.Log("Directory created.." + destDirName);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
    }

    // Get the file contents of the directory to copy.
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();

    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        // Create the path to the new copy of the file.
        string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);

        // Copy the file.
        file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
    }

    // If copySubDirs is true, copy the subdirectories.
    if (copySubDirs)
    {

        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
        {
            // Create the subdirectory.
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);

            // Copy the subdirectories.
            DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it's called:

```
string destingationPath = startupFolder + @"\NetworkingDemoPlayerWithNetworkAwareShooting1_Data";
DirectoryCopy("NetworkingDemoPlayerWithNetworkAwareShooting1_Data", destingationPath, true);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to copy the entire contents of a directory in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/best-way-to-copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Your code worked perfectly fine for me... It copied all directories and sub directories. Could you please check the path in calling method once?

Comment: I guess this exception hindering the copy
IOException: Win32 IO returned 112.

Comment: @Anand yes code is correct there was storage problem cristallo mentioned it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I agree that your code looks correct

Windows system error 112 means there is not enough space on the disk

Comment: same  problem but i got exception it is saying IOException: Win32 IO returned 112.

Comment: usually  Windows system error 112 means there is not enough space on the disk

Comment: update this thing in to your code so that i can accept it. Although my code is also valid. anyhow thanks again

Comment: but why do my copied applicaiton not running. and giving me the error "C:\..... player.exe is not a valid win32 application"

Comment: can you compare source and destination file? Are binary identical?

Comment: exe file which i am copying is not full copied. it is actually 16 mb while it showing 16 kb only.  File.Copy(ownPath, Path.Combine(startupFolder, "Player.exe"));

Comment: I suggest you to use also the third parameter of the copy method, File.Copy(ownPath, Path.Combine(startupFolder, "Player.exe"), true)

it enables the overwriting

Comment: actually the problem is exe is open when its copying .

Comment: generically speaking it should not be a problem, I am pretty confused

Comment: so what to is the problem? I used this code to copy my exe into destination folder and it happen when application is running File.Copy(ownPath, Path.Combine(startupFolder, "Player.exe"));

Comment: Did you try to use the overwriting flag?

Comment: it could be related to the windows security system. can you verify if your exe file is blocked?
see this article http://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-windows-blocked-access-file